# Laravel 5.3 Reflection error even Controller exists

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have created laravel controller and routes. I check the files every thing is in it. It works fine with homestead. But when I upload it on server it gives me reflection error. Any idea? I am using `Centos 7` with `php 5.6`

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 749:
Class App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Takeaway\package\PackageController does not exist
in Container.php line 749
at ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Takeaway\package\PackageController') in Container.php line 749
at Container->build('App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Takeaway\package\PackageController', array()) in Container.php line 644
at Container->make('App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Takeaway\package\PackageController', array()) in Application.php line 709
at Application->make('App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Takeaway\package\PackageController') in Route.php line 203
at Route->getController() in Route.php line 316
at Route->controllerMiddleware() in Route.php line 278
at Route->gatherMiddleware() in Router.php line 666
at Router->gatherRouteMiddleware(object(Route)) in Router.php line 646
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 51
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Answer (score 1):

Check namespace of the file and of the route. It must be like the following

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Takeaway\package`
```

Route must contain namespace suffix:

```
Route::get('/url', 'Backend\Takeaway\package@actionname')
    ->name('routename');
```

Thats due to a base namespace in `RouteServiceProvider` :

`protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';`

P.S. In any strange situation I run `composer dump-autoload`)

Comment: I would definitely do composer dumpautoload, all these weird errors if you changed some class name or create new and it seems like it can't find come classes - just do composer dumpautoload, almost always fixes these kinds of errors

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. its because i not taking proper naming convention.

i have change Packages in my route class. as its case sensitive